# Adding ProgressBar in Layer-list of splash screen

Tags: android, progress-bar, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash-screen for my application in such a way that doesn't have a *cold start*.I came up with this:

**splash_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_img" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        currentUser= mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                if(currentUser==null){
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

There is no error here Everything is working perfectly. But in this way I haven't used a layout and hence cannot use the progress bar `<ProgressBar>`. How do i add it here? Plus I am only able to use  `gravity attribute` of placing the elements on the screen with makes placement of things pretty limited. Is there any other way i can place elements/items on the screen except gravity?

*Gist of the Question: How do I add progress bar to this splash screen at a certain location?*

Thank you!

Comment: You have both a splash screen with `android:windowBackground` and an activity? You can't have a progress bar in the background drawable. In the activity, just add it to your activity's layout. Also, 5 seconds is a damn long splash screen.

Comment: 5 secs is just testing ...will change it. No i don't have both. See `onCreate` method there is no layout being set there, just this `windowBackground`

Comment: If you only intend on using `windowBackground`, I suggest you set the splash theme directly to your MainActivity and drop the SplashActivity, it'll be smoother. Just call `setTheme(R.style.<normal theme>)` in MainActivity `onCreate`. If you want a progress bar however, you'll need the activity, because a ProgressBar is a view not a drawable, so it can't be added to `windowBackground`. Again, I recommend just using MainActivity with a SplashFragment, instead of a SplashActivity.

Comment: Like i said this is just testing, thanks for recommendations on activities. Not even custom Progress-bar is possible???  And what about elements positioning on the screen?

Comment: All animations [are off the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753488/5288316). For positioning, you can adjust padding on the sides of your bitmap. Like I said use a fragment if you want anything more than displaying a static bitmap.

Comment: Thank you for linking that question here. That makes a lot of sense. i read this [today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) . I think I'll keep this question as is and not delete it since there isn't direct duplicate of it. Feel free to answer i'll accept. Thankyou so much for your time.